# selenium can not get changed attribute value

Tags: python, selenium, click

I use selenium to craw page data, some action should be performed on page like this:
1. locate a element and click on it , the click call a js funtion
2. above js function change  tag a's href valve ,I should get the new href.
However, I failed , href value stay all the same! here is the code pices.

```
class wait_for_href_changed(object):
def __init__(self, locator, old):
    self.locator = locator
    self.href = old

def __call__(self, driver):
    try:
        element_href = EC._find_element(driver, self.locator).get_attribute('href')
        return element_href != self.href
    except :
        return False
```

.....

```
    for i in range(1,3):
        for j in range(1,10):
            try:


                old_href = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainTable"]/tbody[1]/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a').get_attribute('href')
                nexts = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="secTable"]/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td['+str(j)+']')
                nexts.click()

                #self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()',nexts)

                element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                     wait_for_href_changed((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainTable"]/tbody[1]/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a'),old_href))

                target = element.get_attribute('href')

                yield Request(target,callback=self.parse2)

            except:
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you are not waiting for the href to change, just asking once if it has changed. It can take a while for the href to be changed. You could simulate the wait by asking if it has changed a number of times and if not wait a second at a time. The pseudocode looks something like it:

```
int secs_to_wait := 5
int secs_waited := 0

while secs_waited < secs_to_wait do:

    element_href = EC._find_element(driver,self.locator).get_attribute('href')
    if element_href != self.href then:
         return true
    end if

    Thread.Sleep(1000)
    secs_waited++
end while

return false;
```